# intel hdmi sound does not work on ubuntu 20.04

Tags: drivers, sound, hdmi, intel

**Ubuntu**: 20.04.03
**Kernel**: 5.15.13
**Motherboard**: MSI Pro Z690-A WIFI (MS-7D25)
**Processor**: I9 12900k

**My problem is with the sound through the HDMI.**

I have already tried several things and possible solutions, with updating x-org, using ppa with new drivers, restarting pulse-audio, downloading a pulse-audio driver, and several possible solutions that I found here and elsewhere.

None worked for me, in the configuration part, it did not even appear in the audio part, the hdmi. The video looks perfect.

I updated to kernel 5.15 and there I recognized some things (wifi, bluetooth), but none of the audio over hdmi.

Comment: When you go to `Settings`->`Sound` does HDMI show in the list of output devices?

Comment: @Bovine No it doesn't even show up

Comment: My only other thought would be to try a different HDMI cable and also try connecting to a different monitor or a TV to see what happens.

Comment: Cable and hardware are working properly. It's a controller issue

Answer (score 1):

**Solution**:

You have to add the following parameter to the kernel:

```
i915.force_probe=4680
```

For that you have to do:

```
sudo nano /etc/default/grub
```

Inside add the code to the line, it would look similar to this:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash i915.force_probe=4680"
```

You save the changes to the file and then update the grub

```
sudo update-grub
```

Then you restart and you should see the hdmi option working:

```
sudo reboot now
```